# How to use Laravel eager loading on model that belongsTo same class

Tags: php, laravel

I have following code:

In a Category Model

```
public function posts()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class, 'post__post_category_relations', 'category_id');
}

public function children()
{
  return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id');
}
```

In a Category Controller:

```
public function index(Category $category){
  $category_childrens = $category->children;
  $posts = ???;
  return view('show.posts',compact('posts'));
}
```

I am trying to retrieve the `$posts` associated with `$category_childrens` and pass them to my view.

Comment: What do you mean by merge? Are you talking about a `join`?

Comment: Yes, I am talking about join! Sorry my english is not good!

Comment: AFAIK, if you have setup the relationships, it should automatically pull the respective data from the tables when you query the model.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I join with Eloquent: Relationships? (Laravel 5.3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42641789/how-can-i-join-with-eloquent-relationships-laravel-5-3)

Comment: Check the duplicate I have linked, you should be able to use `with` from what I can tell. Be sure to up-vote both the question and answer if it helps.

Comment: Sorry, It is not answer. I want join posts from one Model.

Comment: `$posts = $category->posts()->get()`

Comment: @user1491032 Sorry, I want join posts of each $category_children!

Comment: `$posts = $category_childrens->get()->load('posts')` or `$posts = $category_childrens->with('posts')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution in here:

[Laravel get all products from infinity nested categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39093420/laravel-get-all-products-from-infinity-nested-categories)

My script:

In a Category Model:

```
public static function getAllPosts($category, $posts = null)
{
    if ($posts == null) {
        $posts = collect();
    }
    $posts = $posts->merge($category->posts);

    foreach($category->children as $child){
        $posts = self::getAllPosts($child, $posts);
    }

    return $posts;
}
```

In a Controller:

```
....
$category = $this->category->findBySlug($_GET['category_name']);

$posts = Category::getAllPosts($category);

return view('post::admin.posts.index', compact('posts','category','categories'));
```